# Proving $\lVert x \rVert_3$ is smaller than euclidean norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Is there a simple way to show that $\lVert x \rVert_3\leqslant \lVert x \rVert_2$ for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I've used the result in another problem but can't figure out where to get it from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at general $p<q$. Since the inequality
$$ \lVert x \rVert_p \geqslant \lVert x \rVert_q $$
is homogeneous (i.e. it is unchanged by $x \mapsto \lambda x$ for scalar lambda), we can assume $\lVert x \rVert_p = 1$ (the inequality's trivial for $x=0$, of course). Therefore every component, $x_i$, of $x$, satisfies $\lvert x_i \rvert<1$, so $\lvert x_i \rvert^{q-p} \leqslant 1 $. Hence
$$ 1= \lVert x \rVert_p^p = \sum_{i} \lvert x_i \rvert^p \geqslant \sum_{i} \lvert x_i \rvert^q = \lVert x \rVert_q^q, $$
because we multiplied each term by something that is at most $1$.